# (OpenMP) How to start each function 1 time in 1 thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, openmp

I have 4 threads and I want to start in one time 3 functions. Each function takes one thread.
But this code is starting every function 4 times

```
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        Func1();
        Func2();
        Func3();
    }
```

and I have this result:

Func**1** started

Func**1** started

Func**1** started

Func**1** started

Func**1** finished

Func**1** finished

Func**1** finished

Func**1** finished

Func**2** started

Func**2** started

Func**2** started

Func**2** started

Func**2** finished

Func**2** finished

Func**2** finished

Func**2** finished

...

How should I change the code to display some like this:

Func**1** started

Func**2** started

Func**3** started

Func**2** finished

Func**1** finished

Func**3** finished

Comment: You learn how parallelism works.  You're creating subprocesses that call func1, func2, and func3, and then starting them all at effectively the same time.  Each process is going to run func1 first, as soon as it can.  If that's not what you want, then stop trying to disguise one process as four.

Comment: ok. how i can stop to disguise one process as four?

Comment: K, i misread.  Problem is, you have three functions doing three different things.  That's generally not what OMP does.  It's for massively parallel stuff, where you have a bunch of subprocesses doing the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute functions in parallel using openmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431821/execute-functions-in-parallel-using-openmp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are searching for is the `sections` worksharing construct. The syntax should be the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp sections
  {
#pragma omp section
    Func1();
#pragma omp section
    Func2();
#pragma omp section
    Func3();
  }
}
```

I suggest you to  refer to the [specifications](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf) and the examples therein for more information on how this construct works.

Comment: One could also use the combined `parallel sections` construct for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered by Massimiliano, the easiest way to achieve what you want is to use the `sections` construct:

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    Func1();
    #pragma omp section
    Func2();
    #pragma omp section
    Func3();
}
```

(when the `sections` construct is the only thing nested inside a `parallel` region, both pragmas can be combined as shown)

Each `section` scopes the statement or block immediately following it. E.g. if you'd like to include some more code in a section, you should put it inside a block:

```
#pragma omp section
{
    Func1();
    SomeOtherFunc1();
}
```

A more general way to control what each thread does is to examine the thread ID as returned by `omp_get_thread_num()` and to branch in accordance. This resembles the way MPI programs are written:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    switch (omp_get_thread_num())
    {
        case 0:
            Func1();
            break;
        case 1:
            Func2();
            break;
        case 2:
            Func3();
            break;
        default:
            // Do nothing
     }
}
```

One obvious disadvantage is that it would only work unless there are at least 3 threads in the team that executes the parallel region, i.e. code that relies on thread IDs becomes somewhat non-portable. In contrast, the `sections` directive works with any number of threads, e.g. if there is only one thread, all sections would be executed sequentially.